# Is it possible to interrupt io.Copy by closing src?

Tags: go, io

The sample of code:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    sigintCh := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigintCh, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        io.Copy(os.Stdout, os.Stdin)
    }()

    <-sigintCh

    os.Stdin.Close()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

If run this sample and try to interrupt by `^C` it waits for any input and stops only after sending something to stdin (e.g. just press enter).

I expect that closing Stdin will be like sending EOF, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Matt Ryer discusses this [in his blog](https://pace.dev/blog/2020/02/03/context-aware-ioreader-for-golang-by-mat-ryer.html) - without the need to close the `io.Reader` - details below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing `os.Stdin` will cause `io.Copy` to return with error `file already closed` next time it reads from it (after `CTRL-C`, try pressing `Enter`).

As explained in the [File.Close](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Close) docs:

> Close closes the File, rendering it unusable for I/O.

You cannot force an EOF return from `os.Stdin` by closing it (or any other way). Instead, you would need to either wrap `os.Stdin` and implement your own `Read` method that conditionally returns `EOF`, or read a limited number of bytes in a loop.

You can see some more discussion and possible workarounds on this [golang-nuts](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/mjGPLVJp0mQ) thread.

Comment: curious if one could reinitialize `os.Stdin` after closing it: From the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-variables) its simply initialized like so `Stdin  = NewFile(uintptr(syscall.Stdin), "/dev/stdin")`

Answer (score 2):

You can interrupt an `io.Copy` *without* closing the source side - by passing an `io.Reader` that has been wrapped with logic that takes a cancelable `context.Context` outlined [here](https://pace.dev/blog/2020/02/03/context-aware-ioreader-for-golang-by-mat-ryer.html).

Modify your above goroutine like so:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

go func() {
    defer wg.Done()

    r := NewReader(ctx, os.Stdin) // wrap io.Reader to make it context-aware
    _, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, r)
    if err != nil {
        // context.Canceled error if interrupted
    }
}()

<-sigintCh
cancel() // canceling context will interrupt io.Copy operation
```

You can import `NewReader` from an external package like [github.com/jbenet/go-context/io](https://godoc.org/github.com/jbenet/go-context/io) or inline a snippet from the blog link above:

```
type readerCtx struct {
    ctx context.Context
    r   io.Reader
}

func (r *readerCtx) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if err := r.ctx.Err(); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return r.r.Read(p)
}

// NewReader gets a context-aware io.Reader.
func NewReader(ctx context.Context, r io.Reader) io.Reader {
    return &readerCtx{ctx: ctx, r: r}
}
```

Comment: It doesn't interrupt a Read call. I'm not sure that is a good idea to hide the problem behind the call and "one-more" goroutine.

Infinite Read is a strange case. And it's the first time when I came across it. I think logic should be clear and simple. E.g. goroutine with Read should be ignored on application exit or should have a read deadline.

Comment: Yes - didn't want to complicate the answer - but yes you are correct the above will not catch the case of underlying Read blocking forever. There is workarounds for this. When I'm dealing with TCP apps which use `net.Conn`, not only is this an `io.Reader` (and `io.Writer`) - it also has `SetReadDeadline` and `SetWriteDeadline`. Leveraging those with the above cancel logic - will unblock any Read/Write - even after the fact.

Comment: @AlekseyBakin interestingly `os.Stdin` of type `*os.File` *does* support SetReadDeadline. Using this on net.Conn io.Readers allows for early cancelation - but if I tried using it on an *os.File it did not seem to work (at least on MacOS):https://play.golang.org/p/40e_Yz3qFxQ